# My Core Data one-to-many objects seem to be losing their class

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a project which uses Core Data. There is an entity called CDGroup which has a one to many relationship with an entity called CDChapter, the relationship is called chapters. They both have corresponding classes (which are subclasses of NSManagedObject.)

When I retrieve a CDGroup object its class is CDGroup which is correct, the issue however is that if I then attempt to access the chapters set of that group like this:

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[group.chapters objectAtIndex:0].name);
```

I get an error because the chapter that is retrieved is of type NSManagedObject not CDChapter. I've tried casting the chapter to the correct class but I still get the same issue.

How do I make this work?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dot notation with cast objects. Either split the call out into two lines:

```
CDChapter *chapter = [[group.chapters allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",chapter.name);
```

Or use the accessor method rather than dot notation:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[(CDChapter*)[[group.chapters allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

chapters refers to an NSSet of objects that belong to the relationship. Try using:

```
((CDChapter*)[[group.chapters allObjects] objectAtIndex:0]).name;
```